# drag an image with the cursor using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouse, onmousemove

i have a div with a background image and when i press and hold down on it a can drag the image within the div via setting the background position to the cursor position

```
const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState({});
const [imageCenter, setImageCenter] = useState(`center`);
const [onImage, setOnImage] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
  setMousePos({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

return () => {
  window.removeEventListener(
    'mousemove',
    handleMouseMove
  );
};
}, []);
```

the div

```
<div style={{height:`100%`,width:`100vw`,background:`url(${displayImage}) no-repeat ${imageCenter} / cover`,position:`relative`}} onMouseDown={() => setOnImage(true)} onMouseUp={() => setOnImage(false)} onMouseMove={() => {
        if (onImage) {
          setImageCenter(`${mousePos.x - (window.innerWidth / 2)}px ${mousePos.y - (window.innerHeight / 2)}px`)
        }
      }}>
      </div>
```

but when i drag the image the cursor always goes to the center of the image no matter where i left the image inside the frame, i want to make it so that when i hold down and move the image and then press again the focal point is where i pressed not the center of the image

Comment: Are you saying that the center of the image is not equal to the cursor position? If that's the case, you will need to add an offset value of div, eg. getBoundingClientRect().

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix it, the image is dragged by the cursor position

```
const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState({});
const [imageCenter, setImageCenter] = useState(`0px, 0px`);
const [onImage, setOnImage] = useState(false);
const [distanceX, setDistanceX] = useState(null);
const [distanceY, setDistanceY] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
  setMousePos({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });
};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

return () => {
  window.removeEventListener(
    'mousemove',
    handleMouseMove
  );
};
}, []);
```

the div

```
<div style={{height:`100%`,width:`100vw`,backgroundImage:`url(${displayImage})`,backgroundRepeat:`no-repeat`,backgroundPosition:imageCenter,backgroundSize:`cover`,position:`relative`}} onMouseDown={e => {
        setOnImage(true)
        setDistanceX(mousePos.x - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e.target).getPropertyValue("background-position").split(' ')[0].slice(0, -2)))
        setDistanceY(mousePos.y - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e.target).getPropertyValue("background-position").split(' ')[1].slice(0, -2)))
      }} onMouseUp={() => setOnImage(false)} onMouseMove={e => {
        if (onImage) {
          setImageCenter(`${mousePos.x - distanceX}px ${mousePos.y - distanceY}px`)
        }
      }}>
      </div>
```